# Ассемблер, команда ADD

Tags: ассемблер

Есть некоторые примеры команды `ADD`, в которых немного сомневаюсь, проверьте, пожалуйста.

1. `ADD A9D5, DX`

   Операнд-приемник: число `A9D5`, тип - слово.

   Операнд-источник: регистр `DX`, тип -слово.

   **Команда сложит содержимое регистра `DX` и число `A9D5`(тогда куда поместится результат)?**
2. `ADD DL, [B167] ; [B167] = B7`

   **Команда не выполнится из-за несовпадения типов?**
3. `ADD AL, [BX] ; AL=5D, BX=F47A, [F47A]=D3`

   **Команда не выполнится из-за несовпадения типов?**
4. `ADD 5B3D, [B167]`

   Операнд-приемник `5B3D`, тип - слово. (до выполнения)

   Операнд-источник `[B167]`, тип - слово. (до выполнения)

Команда сложит содержимое ячейки памяти, находящееся в ячейках ОП по адресу `B167`, (т. е. в ячейках `B167` и `B168`) и операнд-приемник `5B3D`.

Comment: Какой именно ассемблер? Для какого процессора (системы команд)?

Answer (score 0):

1. в память
2. нужно указать размер операнда `word ptr`, в разных языках по разному.
3. нужно указать размер операнда `word ptr`
4. два числа в памяти сложить нельзя.